# how to make numerical verification easier?

Tags: python

I'm making a program for gradients and I want to check that each element is less than 255

```
g = 57885
h = 345
j = 8


def check(r, g, b):
    if r > 255:
        r = 255
    if g > 255:
        g = 255
    if b > 255:
        b = 255
       
check(g, h, j)
```

tell me how to do it! maybe there is a built-in check?

Comment: The code is different of what you expect: `that each element is less than 255`. The nested ifs are saying that all elements are above 255. Could you add some (toy) input and the expected output?

Comment: g = 57885
h = 345
j = 35467
def check(r, g, b):
    if r > 255:
        if g > 255:
            if b > 255:
                r = 255
                g = 255
                b = 255
                print(r, g, b)
check(g, h, j)
#I want g, h, j to be equal 255

Comment: @Dimagostev just wanted to clear out.. if all number greater than 255 than you need to change each of them individually and if they are not than you don't need to change individually??

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this where you check if all values are greater than 255 in one statement:

```py
def check(r, g, b):
    if all(x > 255 for x in (r, g, b)):
        print('(r, g, b) all above 255')
    else:
        print('one or more of (r, g, b) lt or equal to 255')
```

Comment: I need every number greater than 255 to change individually